# mootools incompatibility with jQuery

Tags: jquery

The following jQuery snippet fails if a page also includes mootools-core.js.

The foo2 object has no elements. This is because find("#content") fails to return anything.

```
var foo1 = $("<div><div id='content'>HAGGIS</div></div>");  
var foo2 = foo1.find("#content");

alert("foo1("+foo1.length+"): "+$('<div>').append(foo1.clone()).remove().html()  
    + "\n\n" +  
      "foo2("+foo2.length+"): "+$('<div>').append(foo2.clone()).remove().html());
```

Comment: What are you experiencing that makes you think that it isn't? I just put up here: http://jsfiddle.net/eSGBx/ and it seems like it is showing what you would expect.

Comment: @spinion, my alert box says "foo2(0): " telling me foo2 is empty. But I tried your link and I see it works there. Hmmm....

Comment: I just tested it as well and it works fine.

Comment: Works for me.
Tried in Firebug console and it works. (Without alert.)

Comment: Ok the plot thickens. The site I'm working on uses mootools. When a page includes mootools-core.js, the above jQuery snippet doesn't work (foo2 is empty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is confirmed to be a problem with mootools.

mootools overrides Element.getElementById, and jQuery's find("#content") thereafter fails.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-noconflict-mootools-load-does-not-work-with-specified-div

Answer (score 1):

getElementById is in Document object so this is the correct code:

```
Document.prototype._getElementById = Document.prototype.getElementById;
```

This only works in Chrome (9.0.597.98), I will try another solution...

New Edit: Happly got it! Works in all tested browsers (hoooray!):

```
document._getElementById = document.getElementById;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of `getElementById` and make jQuery call that one instead. Do this BEFORE mootools gets imported:

```
Element.prototype._getElementById = Element.prototype.getElementById;
```

Then do a search and replace in your jQuery source for `context.getElementById` and replace with `context._getElementById`. There are only 4 occurences in jquery-1.4.4.